# android game supporting multiple screens

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I am creating a small game, and I am really confused how to support for multiple screens.

In some devices my images shows good result but in some other image stretches. I have seen many questions in Stack Overflow, saw some videos,  read some other tutorials from various sites, and seen the Developers Android page but can't find out how to fix it.

When I code views with `xml`, I set units to do least get close results in different screens. But when I work with images it's too hard to support all devices. or else iI can't figure it.

One tutorial I looked at was: http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-different-screen-sizes/ It didn't shared any code, and in other tutorials i found orthographic camara and some related stuff, and in some I found letter boxing.

Letter boxing was clear to understand but no sample code anywhere. **How would I adjust images in screens of various sizes by maintaining aspect ratio and sample code for letter boxing? What is orthographic camara? What would be the sample code?**  It would be great if shared a sample code so that I can figure out how they work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go through the link given below

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Have multiple copies of images each of various size recommended for each devices and place it in the corresponding layout folders

This might help you to solve your problem

Comment: ive already saw all those developer pages related to supporting screens. i want to know a sample code for supporting different screens with a image. anyways thanks for the reply

Comment: just place the images to corresponding folders. Android itself will automatically select the folder for corresponding devices. and Images are the only problem? or you are having problems in the layout arrangements i mean margins and related stuffs?

Comment: my major problem is with images. and have a little prob with layouts too. though i set there positons relative to one other and with dpi they are changing positions with change in screens.

Comment: i have one more clarification. now ill create folders like drawable-mdpi,hdpi,xdpi and all. but how can i know or calculate what images to be placed in which folder. can we calculate dpi for a image? what order we need to place images in respective folders. @venkatesh

Comment: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html. This link will be helpful for you to change the size of the image.

Comment: is that link only applicable to launcher icon or all drawable images?